# Intersection of trig function

Tags: functions

There are two trig function graphs on the same set of axis. $f(x)=\sin(2x)$ and $g(x)=\cos(3x)$. How do I go about finding the points of intersection of the two graphs?

Comment: Solve the equations f and g!

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos3x=\sin2x=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-2x\right)$$

$$\implies3x=2m\pi\pm\left(\frac\pi2-2x\right)$$ where $m$ is any integer

Check for +,- sign one by one

---

Alternatively,

$$\sin2x=\cos3x=\sin\left(\frac\pi2-3x\right)$$

$$2x=n\pi+(-1)^n\left(\frac\pi2-3x\right)$$ where $n$ is any integer

Check for even$(2r)$, odd$(2r+1)$ values of $n$ one by one
,  where $r$ is any integer